# Background color of the layout automatically changed to white

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I have used this color: #7A96A0 in many places in my application. Everything looks fine. But sometimes when I change screen or swipe, background color of the layout is automatically changed to white.This is happening in my entire application. And it  happens only for this color. Is something wrong with this color code. I have given the background to the layout in Xml file. is anyone facing similar problem. Thanks in Advance..

Comment: Have you set any background colour in your theme?

Comment: You should show us the code where you use it.

Comment: I'm setting the background color in the xml file

Answer (score 1):

there is no problem with the color code, `"#7a96a0"` is a valid color code.
I think u should add value and name in color property in strings.xml, then use it in your android xml.

```
go to res >> values >> strings.xml
```

then add

```
<color name="colour">#7a96a0</color>
```

in strings.xml

after that go to xml files and add

```
<android:background="@color/colour">
```

wherever you want to use that color .

Hope this helps

Comment: I did the same thing..I added a value and name in the xml file

Answer (score 0):

i have same problem whit one of my app
change your background source and link it to a **shape** like this:

**shape**: shape_sample.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >
    <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
</shape>
```

and in your **layout**
**layout**: my_layout.xml

```
<TextBox
   android:id="@+id/my_item_textView"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:background="@drawable/shape_sample" />
```

it work for me, i hope it help to you.